# Why not learn the multi-variate chain rule in Calculus I?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, education

I am wondering why we don't learn the multi-variate chain rule in Calculus I?  I know the name implies it is more suitable for multi-variable Calculus, but after learning it, I've found it very useful.  Notably, one does not need to remember product rule or quotient rule or regular chain rule, and I don't think you would have to learn about logarithmic differentiation either.

So with all these advantages, why don't we teach it?

Comment: Why do you think that chain rule or quotient rule become obsolet ?

Comment: How do you get the derivative of $x\sin x$ using that rule?

Comment: @Peter they just don't seem as applicable to as many cases.  Take $y=x^x$.  Logarithmic differentiation and multi-chain rule are the only clear ways to go about taking the derivative.  I just feel it's so easy to use.

Comment: @mlf You can the derivative of $f(u,v)=uv$, where $u=x$ and $v=\sin x$

Comment: The multivariable chain rule isn't needed for $x^x=e^{x\ln x}$; taking the regular chain rule with $u=x\ln x$ works fine. (Though you could count that as log-differentiation in disguise.)

Comment: @Semiclassical while most definitely not necessary, I think it is easy to use.  Not much manipulation is required to do that with multi-variable chain rule.  Doing it your way requires regular chain rule, product rule, and the derivative of $\ln$.

Comment: Presumably, you mean the specific instance of the chain rule in which $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^n$, and we want to differentiate $f \circ g$.

Comment: Even with the chain rule established, logarithmic differentiation gives you a lot for a little.

Comment: technically this would go on matheducators.SE

Comment: The most popular notation for partial derivatives is awkward and also a lie; $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is not determined by $u$ and $x$, one needs to use some hidden information to determine it. One dimension really is a huge simplifier. I actually have a pet belief that differential calculus is much better expressed in terms of differentials rather than in terms of partial derivatives, and the traditional approach gets the benefits of differentials "by accident" since one dimension doesn't have enough wiggle room to mess things up.

Comment: @djechlin that place is more for how to teach I think.

Comment: @SimpleArt you seem to be asking why it's not taught in Calc I. you can learn it whenever you want. I think your top answer is good but ME may have answers from people who think about this quite a lot.

Comment: @djechlin one can learn almost anything they are into whenever they want.  And yeah, I'm really waiting for more answers.

Comment: To all non-US users asking *"What the hell is Calculus I?"*, 'Calculus I' is the introductory (first-year college) course to calculus in the US. Other countries will have different syllabi, and in fact most teach univariate chain-rule in high-school.

Comment: @smci I would think to most, Calculus I would most obviously mean first calculus, as its name would most likely suggest.  And I am not interested in univariate chain-rule, as should be obvious.

Comment: @SimpleArt: you asked 'Calculus I', not 'an introductory calculus course' (whether high-school or college, and first-year or second-year). In some countries much of this is high-school math, and we don't even divide into separate courses for calculus, statistics etc. If you're generically inquiring about first-year college calculus courses in all countries, it needs retitling.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I used to think this, too, until I taught Calculus I.

If you, as a math student and enthusiast, like to see the product rule, etc., as special cases of the multivariate chain rule, then that is good for you and deepens your understanding.

However, my experience has been that reasoning from the general to the specific doesn't always sink in to the novice learner.  If the multivariate chain rule is mumbo-jumbo, nothing derived from it is understandable either.

The median student in Calculus I struggles with the concept of function, has trouble working with more than two variables, and can't keep straight whether $\frac{1}{x}$ is the derivative of $\ln x$ or the other way around.  I'm not trying to bash Calculus I students; only to recognize that they are in a different place mathematically than we are now, or even than we were when we first learned Calculus I.  To reach them, we have to understand where their frontiers are and what is just beyond them.

Comment: Yes, this always true.  $\ddot\smile$ probably why I joined this site, to be with more of the same type of math people.

Comment: For some reason I thought for the first quarter of Calculus I the product rule was the definition of the operator to multiply differentials.

Comment: Goodness, this is most popular answer of the day.

Comment: Good job on reaching that!

Comment: I'd agree for sure but this is one of the many reasons that it doesn't make sense to have mathematics students and physics/engineering students in the same class for the first three (and perhaps most formative) semesters of the undergrad years. The disciplines have two totally different mindsets/goals and usually the class ends up exclusively catering to the physics/engineering crowd.